# Add together lists of tuples

Tags: python

I have two lists of integers:

```
xList = [(1, 2), (3,4)]
yList = [(5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

I want to add the first element of xList to the first element of yList etc so that the output is as follows

```
[(6, 8), (10, 12)]
```

Any ideas that I can try using numpy or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a pure-Python approach you can use [operator.add(a, b)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.add) (returns `a + b`) from the `operator` module combined with the built-in functions [map(function, iterable, ...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [zip(*iterables, strict=False)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). The `map` function "[r]eturn[s] an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results" and the `zip` function iterates over several iterables in parallel, successively yielding tuples of these elements.

```
import operator

xList = [(1, 2), (3,4)]
yList = [(5, 6), (7, 8)]

res = [tuple(map(operator.add, a, b)) for a, b in zip(xList, yList)]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[(6, 8), (10, 12)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a list comprehension:

```
out = [tuple(map(sum, zip(*x))) for x in zip(xList, yList)]
```

Output:

```
[(6, 8), (10, 12)]
```

##### generalization

This works independently of the number of input lists. For more lists:

```
lists = [wList, xList, yList, zList]

out = [tuple(map(sum, zip(*x))) for x in zip(*lists)]
```

###### input of uneven size

Use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
xList = [(1, 2), (3,4)]
yList = [(5, 6), (7, 8)]
zList = [(1,1)]

from itertools import zip_longest
lists = [xList, yList, zList]
out = [tuple(map(sum, zip(*x)))
       for x in zip_longest(*lists, fillvalue=(0,0))]
```

Output:

```
[(7, 9), (10, 12)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[(a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1]) for a, b in zip(xList, yList)]
```

Comment: How could this be adapted for lists of varying sizes without manually entering in the addition for each element?

Comment: @JackWeir do you really mean lists of varying sizes (can you edit your question with an example)? Or a varying number of lists (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72107022/16343464))?

Comment: @JackWeir Could you clarify with some more example inputs and outputs in the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
x = np.array(xList)
y = np.array(yList)
print(x + y)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 6,  8],
       [10, 12]])
```

To make your *exact* desired output, though I doubt it'll matter:

```
print([*map(tuple, (x + y))])
...
[(6, 8), (10, 12)]
```

Comment: I think that he wants an array of tuples actually.

Comment: @meph Made an edit with that as well~ Though I agree with the consensus that numpy is overkill for this. - it's not bad to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` is overkill for this problem. All you need is `zip()` and a list comprehension:

```py
[(x1 + y1, x2 + y2) for (x1, x2), (y1, y2) in zip(xList, yList)]
```

This outputs:

```py
[(6, 8), (10, 12)]
```